# How to make the Rust Game of Life WebAssembly work as a static website?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack, rust-wasm

I have gone through the tutorial for the Rust Game of Life and have a working game in a web browser, but it only works from the demo web server that comes bundled with it. I can start the server with `npm start` and it runs the webpack-dev-server on port 8080. When I access the site through that port, it works fine. However, if I try to copy the site to a web server like Apache, it does not load correctly. The error I am currently getting from it is:

```
Error importing `index.js`: TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “wasm-game-of-life”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”. bootstrap.js:5:23
<anonymous> http://www.north-winds.org/gol/bootstrap.js:5
```

From the tutorial, the root of the website is a folder called `www/` in the repository and the generated wasm module from the Rust program is placed under `pkg/`. There is a symbolic link from `www/node_modules/wasm-game-of-life` that points up to `../../pkg/` and I've replaced that symlink with an actual copy of the top-level `pkg/` folder so that the website is entirely contained inside the `www/` folder and then placed that folder on my website at http://www.north-winds.org/gol/, however, accessing it returns the error above. What do I need to modify to make it work stand-alone?

As I understand it, this WebAssembly Game-of-Life is basically a stand-alone client-side app and should not require anything beyond a web server that can provide static files with the appropriate mime-types attached. I don't see anything special that should be required. I did see mention of WebSockets somewhere, but I don't know why that is required for this app. I compared this to the "Hello, World" WebAssembly example for C from https://webassembly.org/ and it ended up with a `.wasm` file generated from the C source code, and a single JavaScript and HTML supporting file to execute it. The files worked correctly when simply copied to static web server location. This is what I'd like for the Rust example.

Some relevant code from the Rust Game-of-Life is as follows. The top-level HTML file includes this among other lines:

```
<script src="./bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The bootstrap JavaScript file contains only this:

```
import("./index.js")
  .catch(e => console.error("Error importing `index.js`:", e));
```

And the index.js file that it references has this among other glue logic for the Wasm:

```
import { Universe, Cell } from "wasm-game-of-life";                             
                                                                            
// Import the WebAssembly memory at the top of the file.                        
import { memory } from "wasm-game-of-life/wasm_game_of_life_bg";
```

What's missing to make this work standalone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `www` and `pkg` folders contain the source files you need, but you do not have a static site yet. The [`create-wasm-app`](https://github.com/rustwasm/create-wasm-app) template uses Webpack, so you need to build the final output by running `npm run build` in the `www` folder. This will create a subfolder named `dist` which contains the actual static files that can be placed on your web server.

Comment: That was it! I even ran it with a static-only web server, darkhttpd, all that was required was ensuring it presented the correct mime-types. Surprising how different the filenames are, though, compared to what the template folder started with.